# Блок уменьшается при уменьшении ширины окна. Знаю, что такой вопрос уже задавали, но ответа на него так и не нашел

Tags: html, css

Доброго всем дня или вечера. У меня такой вопрос..

Вот обычный **HTML**-код, с обычным хедером и контейнером внутри:

```
<header class="header">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
</header>
```

Далее идут стили:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header{
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 100px;
}

.container{
    width: 1770px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Проблема в том, что при уменьшении окна браузера, когда хедер становится меньше ширины контейнера, он продолжает уменьшаться, а контейнер в нем нет. Если убрать заданную ширину у контейнера, то проблема решится, но этот способ мне не подходит.

Пробовал задавать одинаковый **background** для хедера и контейнера, визуально все норм, но проблема все равно остается.[image: вот]

Может стоит указывать другие единицы измерения для контейнера кто знает? Хотя я уже пробовал.

Comment: `.container { width: 100%;` или фиксированную ширину задавай родительскому `.header`

Comment: Задавал, проблема в том ,что если не задавать фиксированной ширины для внутреннего блока, то все норм, но стоит задать для .container какую либо ширину то все.

Comment: Так и должно быть. Свойство width устанавливает ширину элемента. По умолчанию она равняется ширине внутренней области. Т.е. ты говоришь, `.container` займи начиная с верхнего левого угла `1770px;` в ширину, а `.header` по умолчанию занимает ширину внутренней области.. Так и получается, у тебя хедер "размером в дисплей", а ширина контейнера больше/меньше..

Comment: Не могли бы вы указать, что явно нужно прописать, чтобы решить эту проблему? Если я укажу для .container { width: 100% }; то он растянется во всю ширину экрана, а мне нужна фиксированная ширина. А задав для .heder фиксированную ширину ничего не происходит. @Ma3rX

Comment: @JackWhite хорошо, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Спасибо, буду ждать